# Xamarin Forms Shell Android bug Tabbar Tab visibility change and unlabeled tabs

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.shell

I created a repo on github that reproduce my issue : https://github.com/ArthurFSharp/BugTabBar

The idea is : i want to hide labels in tabs, so for Android i do it in custom renderer using LabelVisibilityMode property :

```
public class AppTabBarAppearance : ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    public AppTabBarAppearance(IShellContext context, ShellItem shellItem)
        : base(context, shellItem)
    {
    }

    public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        bottomView.ItemIconSize = 100;
        bottomView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityUnlabeled;
        bottomView.Elevation = 0f;
    }
}
```

It works well.

The problem come when i want to hide or show specific tab in the tabbar :

```
<Tab
        Title="Browse"
        Icon="icon_feed.png"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsBrowseMenuVisible}" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>
```

When IsBrowseMenuVisible property change, depending on its value, it show or hide the Browse Tab item, but the labels in the tabs appear again until when change page.

Like tabbar totally resets when i hide a tab but when i navigate in other tab, the renderer is applied again.

UPDATE : To clarify the issue, here is with pictures:

[image]

I arrive in the main page, i check to checkbox to hide the third menu :

[image]

It works, BUT we see that labels in tab item are back, and when i navigate to other page, they gone :

[image]

Comment: is the default value of IsBrowseMenuVisible true? can you share this property code?

Comment: @AmjadS. https://github.com/ArthurFSharp/BugTabBar/blob/7e2ad733ef92d62eee8e62e078c44224a07f1f2a/BugShellTabItemVisible/ViewModels/AppViewModel.cs#L11

Comment: IsBrowseMenuVisible = true; its because your assigning it to true in the constructor , thus every time you navigate to shell page it enter constructor and initialize IsBrowseMenuVisible to true

Comment: i updated my post, I think I misdescribed my problem which has nothing to do with binding, but more with renderer on Android.

Comment: can you put the IsVisible="{Binding IsBrowseMenuVisible}"  also in the shellcontent

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't change anything

Comment: On my test, when navigation, it would recall the renderer to hide the label gain. Keep on testing and would feedback ASAP.